# nav-tabs, navbar-right: bottom bar does not extend to left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap, with `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">`, one gets tabs with the bottom line extending nicely to the right, e.g.,

[image]

The tabs are moved to the right with either  `<ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-right">` or  `<ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">`, the bottom line does *not* extend to the left, e.g.,

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Add the pull-right to the `li` instead

Comment: Yeah @anpsmn that works well: http://bootply.com/0eVAxX5N8V

Comment: nav-tabs isn't a navbar, so navbar-right isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can add classes to your li's as such:
[CodePen Here](http://codepen.io/mobrycki/pen/ZYyYMO)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="active pull-right"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```